# Automatically Deploy App on Heroku Based on User Creation

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Multi-Tenant Django Application working with Postgres on Heroku. Is there a way to actually instantiate a new dyno/db/subdomain based on when a new User is created on my application?

Comment: How are you doing your multi-tenancy?

Comment: Well, I am either planning on doing what I described above where I basically replicate the application(separate database for each tenant)  upon different sub domains, or I will be artificially be isolating each tenancy through a mapping table in Postgres while using only 1 database.

Comment: Have you looked at [`django-tenants`](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants)? It uses PostgreSQL schemas for data isoliaton and subodomains for distinguishing between tenants. There are [other libraries to explore, too](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/multi-tenancy/).

Comment: Wow this is great Chris. I had no idea something this elaborate existed for django already!

Comment: @Chris do you have any idea how I would generate the subdomain on my domain host's end? I understand how to do the wildcard domains on heroku, but don't I need to actually establish the subdomain?

Comment: You could set up a wildcard DNS entry to match all subdomains. In your application you'll probably want to show a sensible page if a subdomain is requested that doesn't map to a tenant.

Comment: @Chris So, update...I actually got everything implemented with django-tenants and it is live. The only thing I don't understand is when I want to generate a new sub-domain, I can do it on Heroku's end no problem, however how would I create a new CName record for that sub-domain without manually going to my DNS?

Comment: Who's your DNS provider?

Comment: @Chris currently it is GoDaddy, but I am going to have the domain transferred to DNSimple

Comment: Okay. I'll add an answer now and include information about that.

Comment: Awesome, I will set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly dependent on how your multi-tenancy is being achieved.

If you haven't already built multi-tenancy into your application I encourage you to look at something like [`django-tenants`](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants), which adds multitenancy support based on subdomains and PostgreSQL schemas. If that's not a good fit you can explore [other similar libraries](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/multi-tenancy/).

Once you've set up `django-tenants` there's not much more to do on the Django side. It all be comes configuration. Requests to configured subdomains will be routed to the appropriate shared or tenant database schema.

But those requests have to make it to your application. That's where DNS comes in, ideally using wildcard subdomains.

First, [add `*.your-domain.tld` to your app's domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain) on the Heroku side:

```
heroku domains:add "*.your-domain.tld"
```

Next, add a wildcard CNAME entry with your DNS provider¹. The exact mechanics of how to do this will vary from provider to provider. You've said you're moving to DNSimple, and it [looks like they support wildcard CNAME records using `*`](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/record-editor/#create-a-record).

---

¹Unfortunately, [some DNS providers like GoDaddy don't support wildcard CNAME entries](https://serverfault.com/a/44635/374091). In that case you'll have to individually create each CNAME record.